# Android Studio: grant permission between installing test APK and running tests with graphical test runner

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to [automate the disabling of animations as described in this post](http://product.reverb.com/2015/06/06/disabling-animations-in-espresso-for-android-testing/), but that only seems to work for command-line invocation of `connectedAndroidTest`. I want to use the graphical test runner in Studio, with the list box showing passed/failed tests. With that runner, the permission grant (`adb shell pm grant ... android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE`) is never run, seemingly because the gradle task `installDebugAndroidTest` is never run, instead the runner is running Gradle as far as `assembleDebugAndroidTest` (or whatever alternate gradle task I specify in my run configuration), and then installing `com.mypackage.test` by some other (non-Gradle?) method immediately before running tests. So any prior permission grant is reset by that installation.

**How can I grant `SET_ANIMATION_SCALE` between the graphical test runner's installation of the test package and the running of the test?**

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have exactly the same issue, really annoying. Started looking into the artifactory build step in Android Studio, but that isnt present in Android Studio lets it is in normal IntelliJ. Thanks.

Comment: I'd really like to know a solution for this as well. Seems like a pretty annoying oversight from the tools team to make this a pre-run-but-post-install requirement and not offer a hookin with IDE.

Comment: I opened a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198813

Comment: I hope that my solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41382575/how-to-request-permissions-on-android-marshmallow-for-junit-tests/41565899#41565899 will help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using reflection, adding the permission to the manifest, creating an Espresso TestRule and a task ([explained here in detail](https://github.com/ardock/android-topeka/issues/1)).

Add the **permission to the manifest** of a debug/mock variant:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE"/>
```

Create **your own task** depending on `installDebug` and make `connectedDebugAndroidTest` depend on your task. You also need to **grant** the [SET_ANIMATION_SCALE permission for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33848860/1009132).

Create a **test rule** that uses internally **reflection** to retrieve and restore animation scales ([code](https://github.com/ardock/android-topeka/tree/65c03fa2e3ae47810de0843196cd278057ed14c8/app/src/androidTest/java/com/google/samples/apps/topeka/rule)):

```
public class AnimationAwareWonderTestRule extends AnimationAwareAwesomeTestRule {

    private float[] mAnimationScales;

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        mAnimationScales = AnimationAwareWonder.tryToRetrieveAndDisableAnimationsAndTransitions();
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() throws Throwable {
        AnimationAwareWonder.tryToRestoreAndEnableAnimationsAndTransitions(mAnimationScales);
    }
}
```

[It works](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/android-topeka/builds/153158638) but seems it's not possible at the moment to use this permission in MarshMallow.