# How to enable read/write contacts permission when run connected Android test?

Tags: android

Task:

Let connected Android tests work well on Android M.

Question:

How to enable read/write contacts permission when run connected Android test?

Problem:

I know pm command could enable the apk's permission.

```
adb shell pm grant <PACKAGE_NAME> <PERMISSION_NAME>
```

I want to run the tests which could run on both real apis and mock apis. If I fail to trigger pm command in gradle DSL, test code is not able to touch real api for security reason.

I try to add the step as first of `connectedAndroidTest (connectedInstrumentTest)` task. It doesn't work for the target apk has not been install yet. The command lines are called with error code.

```
android.testVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.connectedInstrumentTest.doFirst {
        def adb = android.getAdbExe().toString()
        exec {
            commandLine 'echo', "hello, world testVariants"
        }
        exec {
            commandLine adb, 'shell', 'pm', 'grant', variant.testedVariant.applicationId, 'android.permission.READ_ACCOUNTS'
         }
     }
 }
```

I try to add the step as last step of install task. It isn't called when I start `connectedAndroidTest`.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.getBuildType().name == "debug") {
        variant.install.doLast {
            def adb = android.getAdbExe().toString()

            exec {
                commandLine 'echo', "hello, world applicationVariants"
            }
            exec {
                commandLine adb, 'shell', 'pm', 'grant', variant.applicationId, 'android.permission.READ_ACCOUNTS'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My plan is to enable permissions before tests are launched. I don't know which task is proper one. It looks like `connectedVariantAndroidTest` doesn't depend on `installVariant`, though they both call `adb install`.

I try to run the `pm grant` from test cases. It fails as expected.

I will accept other solutions to run the android tests well.

Comment: I think this article and the comments can help you http://product.reverb.com/2015/06/06/disabling-animations-in-espresso-for-android-testing/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you need to create your own task depending on `installDebug` and then make `connectedDebugAndroidTest` depend on your task.

People does it to disable animations and works, you force the app installation and grant your specific permission before the android tests are executed like this:

```
def adb = android.getAdbExe().toString()

task nameofyourtask(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'installDebug') { // or install{productFlavour}{buildType}
    group = 'nameofyourtaskgroup'
    description = 'Describe your task here.'
    def mypermission = 'android.permission.READ_ACCOUNTS'
    commandLine "$adb shell pm grant ${variant.applicationId} $mypermission".split(' ')
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith('connectedDebugAndroidTest')) { // or connected{productFlavour}{buildType}AndroidTest
        task.dependsOn nameofyourtask
    }
}
```

You can add this code to a new `yourtask.gradle` file and add the next line at the bottom of the `build.gradle` file:

```
apply from: "yourtask.gradle"
```

And declare your permission in the proper manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_ACCOUNTS" />
```

**Update:**

Fixed commandLine command like you did on [your version for multiple variants](https://gist.github.com/stonyw/339f16ae8a79660825eb), thanks.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.getBuildType().name == "debug") {
        task "configDevice${variant.name.capitalize()}" (type: Exec){
            dependsOn variant.install

            group = 'nameofyourtaskgroup'
            description = 'Describe your task here.'

            def adb = android.getAdbExe().toString()
            def mypermission = 'android.permission.READ_ACCOUNTS'
            commandLine "$adb shell pm grant ${variant.applicationId} $mypermission".split(' ')
        }
        variant.testVariant.connectedInstrumentTest.dependsOn "configDevice${variant.name.capitalize()}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank Ardock.  [Here is my modified version for multiple variants.](https://gist.github.com/stonyw/339f16ae8a79660825eb)

Comment: Sorry for a noob question, build could you point to a guide or paste your code of how to create a gradle task?

Comment: I don't see when install{flavour}Debug task is ran. It's not shown as a task in the Gradle console when I run the tests, although clearly the apks get installed at some point.

Comment: for me this gives something looking like a permission problem … is the task allowed to perform such actions per default, or possible the operating system prohibiting this? like: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Remote:grantAllDebugPermissions'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'java.lang.UNIXProcess@6081a6a2''
any ideas?

Comment: some times it can be helpful to iterate directly on `testVariants` instead of `applicationVariants`